# Mostrar lista array en Vuejs

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Quiero mostrar mi lista de ingredientes en Vuejs de un jugo, esta lista tiene dentro de un array es decir este es mi objeto json
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
category    
0   
_id "5aa875ab69355c25d0132a41"
title   "Refresh"
ingredient  
0   
category    
0   "5aa875ab69355c25d0132a41"
_id "5aab1df8013dd53774f16578"
name    "Almond Milk"
_id "5aa811e5aa7f7d414c707127"
name    "Confused Strawberry"
image   "j.jpg"
```

pero cuando le digo

```
<!-- <div v-for="ingre in items.ingredient" >
  {{ingredient.name}}
 </div> -->
```

me dice que no reconocer ingredient,

¿Cómo puedo hacer el loop dentro de ingredient para que me de el nombre?

Este es mi codigo de Vue

```
<template>
  <div class="details">

        <h1 class="hidden">Back to Juices</h1>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'DisplayItem' }" id="back">
          BACK TO JUICES
        </router-link>


        <h1 class="hidden">Product Image</h1>
    <div class="img-juice col-xs-6" >
      <img class="image-detail" :src="'../public/images/' + items.image " />

    </div>

        <h1 class="hidden">Product detail</h1>

<div class=" col-xs-6">
 <h2 class="name">{{items.name}}</h2>
 <hr>
 <h2 class="ingre">INGREDIENTS</h2>
 <!-- <div v-for="ingre in items.ingredient" >
  {{ingredient.name}}
 </div> -->
 <h2 class="name">{{items.ingredient}}</h2>



 <h2 class="ingre">CATEGORY</h2>
 <!--<h3 v-for="category in item.categories">{{category.name}}</h3>-->



</div>


 </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  name: 'DetailsItem',
  data () {
    return {
      items: {}
    }
  },
  created () 
  {
     var vm=this;
      axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/item/` + this.$route.params.id).then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        vm.items=response.data;

  })


}
}
</script>
```

¿Qué tengo mal para que no me de el nombre del ingrediente?

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes comentado el código del for?

Comment: Es que esa parte me genera conflicto y no me muestra nada la pagina si lo dejo, por que dice que es un objeto no definido

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si entiendo bien la estructura de tus datos y lo que intentas hacer, deberías iterar primero los items y luego los ingredientes de cada uno, si es que tienes más de uno de estos últimos:

```
<div v-for="item in items">

  {{ item.name }}

  <div v-for="ingre in item.ingredient">

    {{ ingre.name }}

  </div>

</div>
```